# javascript error. password and confirm password have same value, but error is still show

Tags: javascript

Showing error even password matches

```
if (confirmpassword != password ) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Password not match!";
  return false;
};
```

Can't find this error. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. There is not enough code in the question to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: use !== instad of !=

Comment: I suspect `confirmpassword` and `password` are elements, not strings, but there's no way of knowing given the amount of code provided.  Please edit your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

you should use below code:

```
if (confirmpassword !== password ) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Password not match!";
  return false;
} else {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="";
  return true;
};
```

So if this condition is passes, be sure the input characters are not same.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided much info, but I assume you are calling this in an key event or on change evernt. Hope this helps.

```
if (confirmpassword != password ) {
     document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Password not match!";
     return false;
}else{
     document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An explanation is due here as I see you are not familiar with JavaScript terminology and logic.

In JavaScript, There is a difference between `==` and `===`, consider [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp):

**`==`  equal to**

**`===` equal value and equal type**

Meaning that:

```
if (confirmpassword != password ) {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Password not match!";
            return false;
        };
```

Will check that `confirmpassword` and `password` *does not equal to the same value*.

---

```
if (confirmpassword !== password ) {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Password not match!";
            return false;
        };
```

Will check that `confirmpassword` and `password` *does not equal to the same value and type*

---